# sencha touch/ query mobile running on touchscreen pc - virtual keyboard?

Tags: browser, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, touchscreen, virtual-keyboard

I need to develop a browser app for use on a kiosk touchscreen -> no physical keyboard.
I would like to use Sencha-Touch.
The browser would be running on windows or linux/ununtu.

How can users input text?

I am not tied to sencha touch. I can use another framework (query mobile, etc...) if it offers such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it's a jQuery Virtual Keyboard:

- http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/ (Demo)
- https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such a feature, and Sencha Touch definitely does not include it. However, it would not take much to introduce that functionality into the framework.

You would need to:

- design and create your virtual keyboard. This would be a simple component with a HTML template which had buttons for each of the keys. On each key press, you would fire an event.
- in all places you need the keyboard (for example, fields), you would listen to the tap event and then trigger the virtual keyboard. You would then just update the value of the field depending on what the user types.